# How to translate Windows Form app to work in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

so a quick rundown of what I have so far.

I am currently using [GMap.Net](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps). Currently, original site is acting funny, but it is [here](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/).

I have been working on a project that incorporates using this library works perfectly fine on Windows. However, I now need to develop for it on OS X.

I follow a tutorial to help setup C#/Mono/Xamarin to get it all working here `http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-learn-c-sharp-in-os-x-3640347/` So, far it has been working great.

All packages are included properly and I get no error when building.

My only issue at the moment is when running it does not rendering any of the UI elements nor print anything with `Console.WriteLine`.

When I try to run it through Xamarin it just continues to halt. Nothing printed or no error/feedback in the terminal/console.

I also used `xbuild` on the `.sln` file for the project and it creates a `.exe`, however, when I run `mono` on the `exe` file it simply hangs as well.

Here is the entry point in case it helps. Also note this solution was created in Visual Studio 2015 using Windows Form Application.

```
// Program.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyMapProgram
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Main());
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure what else to do to see how else to get it to work properly. I started a simple GTK project and a window popup from the base template. So, everything seems to function in terms of ability to draw UI elements. Is the UI module for rendering on Windows not compatible in Mono?

Comment: You should in most cases develop a Xamarin.Mac app and use native macOS UI elements. Mono WinForms is far from usable, and is mainly a test field for your basic ideas.

Comment: @LexLi So, what would be a common ground in which to be able to use both UI frameworks to be developed on both OS X and Windows? Seems like it would just be easier to use Unity to get this done quicker and no hassle for developing and deploying for cross platform.

Comment: Sounds like you are familiar with "cross platform" things such as Java, but Mono from the start suggests native UI bindings (GTK# on Linux, Xamarin.Mac on macOS, and WinForms/WPF on Windows). You can still share a lot of code though UI parts are OS dependent. Of course, if you are developing a game, Unity or MonoGame can be a better option. There is simply no "universal cross platform UI framework" yet.

Comment: @LexLi Hi, thanks for your input. I think I nice general solution to help me is to go with something along the lines of Electron. Allows me to be cross platform, while also supporting certain features I required, however, it will mean I need to drop from GMAP.NET in place of my own, however, there is already some support of maps in electron.